# How to open video file with custom title

Tags: android

I want to open video file and set the previewed title in video player with a different title than the file name (which is used by default).

```
            String videoFile = "Video file url / path";
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoFile), "video/mp4");
            // Is there an extra to set the previewed video title?
            mMainActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no documented extra for `ACTION_VIEW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) that would offer this, and third-party video players would not have to honor it anyway. You are welcome to implement your own video player in your own app if you wish to control the title.